# how to decomp .cmp files in java code

Tags: compression

I have one requirement which is read `.cmp` files from source directories then decomp and drop it in the target directories. I use the below code to call decomp program but it is not working:

```
String filePath = "C:\\Users\\tizitan.ET\\Desktop\\TDClient\\decomp.exe";                                   
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);
p.waitFor();
InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
int c;                   
while((c = in.read())!= -1){                        
    baos.write(buf, 0, c);
}
baos.close();
```

Pls help